# My google chrome can't append string but firefox can append my string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote this `jquery` code to append my own tag, but on google chrome, this tag is not appended but added on Firefox. What's the reason?

**My jQuery code**

```
<script>
    function addCategory(categoryName, tag) {
        var optionTag = $(tag);
        var iTag = '<i class="category-pick">' + categoryName + '<img src="public/img/cancel.png"></i>';
        var divRow = optionTag.parents('.row2');
        divRow.append(iTag);
    }
</script>
```

**HTML code**

```
<div class="row2">
                                    <span>موضوع مطلب:</span>
                                    <select name="category" autocomplete="off">
                                        <option>انتخاب کنید</option>

                                            <option onclick="addCategory('title 1',this)" value="value 1">
                                                title 1
                                            </option>
                                            <option onclick="addCategory('title 2',this)" value="value 2">
                                                title 2
                                            </option>

                                    </select>
                                </div>
```

Comment: what is `tag` ?

Comment: try using `closest` instead of `parents`

Comment: and can you make a small fiddle ?

Comment: Please add into your question a complete set of code, so that we can see what is calling this, what is in the parameters and also whether the console gives any errors.

Comment: now i add HTML code too !

Comment: Use closest instead of parents, this avoid the append to actually happen but somewhere else...

Comment: I replaced, but not fix it for Chrome!

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#category').on('change', function() {
    var optionTag = $(this);
    var selectedText = optionTag.find("option:selected").text();
    
    if(selectedText=='انتخاب کنید') return;
    
    var iTag = '<i class="category-pick">' + selectedText + '<img src="public/img/cancel.png"></i>';
    
    var divRow = optionTag.parents('.row2');
        divRow.append(iTag);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row2">
   <span>موضوع مطلب:</span>
   <select name="category" id="category" autocomplete="off">
      <option>انتخاب کنید</option>
      <option  value="value 1">
         title 1
      </option>
      <option  value="value 2">
         title 2
      </option>
   </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Now what if the `<option>انتخاب کنید</option>` is not printed?

Comment: @Komeil you don't want it to be printed ?

Comment: Can I pass variable or input to this function?

Comment: @Komeil, if you mean like `on('change', function(param) {}`, I'm not sure you can do that

Comment: Yes, because I need to pass the parameter and want to use PHP too and I can not do this with this code!